# Table style not working in PHP, MySql

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

The table pattern was working before adding the below line

```
echo "<td><a href='get_file.php?quote_id=" . $row['quote_id'] ."'>Download</a></td>";
```

but after adding the above line the table style is gone. 
here is the full table code, please help me in this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Quote ID</th>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>File</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Created</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
         <tbody>
          <?php
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($row["status"]!="Approved")
            {
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>" . $row['quote_id'] . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . $row['mime'] . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . $row['size'] . "</td>";
                 echo "<td>" . $row['created'] . "</td>";
                 echo "<td><a href='get_file.php?quote_id=" . $row['quote_id'] ."'>Download</a></td>";  
                 echo "</tr>";
            }}
            ?>
         </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: got the answer sir @JayHarris its because of the 5 <th>, i have to add one <th> more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 5 `<th>`

And

6 `<td>`

That is why its not working.

Change:

```
<tr>
    <th>Quote ID</th>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>File</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Created</th>
</tr>
```

To

```
<tr>
    <th>Quote ID</th>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>File</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Download</th>
</tr>
```

Also, Change

```
echo "<td><a href='get_file.php?quote_id=" . $row['quote_id'] ."'>Download</a></td>";
```

To

```
echo '<td><a href="get_file.php?quote_id=' . $row['quote_id'] .'">Download</a></td>';
```

Comment: @AakkiRock, if my answer worked for you, please accept it as solution.

Comment: yeah I will sure :) after 6 minutes i can accept this